# Append data in existing file in U-SQL

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

Can we append data in existing file in U-SQL?
I have created a CSV file as output in U-SQL. I am writing another U-SQL query and  I want to append the output of that query in the existing file.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported, and would go against the design of a robust, distributed, idempotent big data system (although you could implement that behaviour by reading the previous output as a rowset and do UNION ALL).

The best way to deal with this is to use partitions properly, for example, create one or more new partitions for each of your executions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621324.aspx

Comment: I'm thinking files sets rather than partitions but similar concept.  ie file1_20161202.csv, file1_20161203.csv etc U-SQL can treat them as one with its file set feature, eg `@q = EXTRACT rowId int, date string FROM "/input/file1_{date}.txt" USING Extractors.Tsv();`.

Comment: @wBob Good idea. To produce such files (in a run triggered by Data Factory), you could pass [Dynamic parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-usql-activity#dynamic-parameters).