# get existing file and append data into an existing file -- U-SQL

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

How can we get an existing file and append data into that file through u-sql script.

`DECLARE @file1 string = "dailyfiles/daily/LATESTMODIFIEDFILENAME.csv";

DECLARE @out string = "/output/result.csv";

@data = EXTRACT col1 string, col2 string, col3 string, col4 string FROM @file1,@file2 USING Extractors.Csv();

APPEND DATA INTO AN EXISTING FILE CODE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem some days ago. Is an workaround but really helps me in my implementation.

I follow the same logic of unions of data to get the final result with updated values:

https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/paul/2016/12/writing-a-u-sql-merge-statement/

Hope this help you!

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid that is not supported in U-SQL,please see this thread: [Append data in existing file in U-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40929858/append-data-in-existing-file-in-u-sql). You could vote up this feedback [link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/15229347-append-to-files-in-u-sql) to push progress of it.

Besides,as workaround,you could use ADLS [Path-Update Rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/vi-vn/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/update#request-body) to implement append.

Firstly,you need to call the `action=append` to push it to the uncommitted buffer on the server.

```
https://$STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME.dfs.core.windows.net/mydata/data/file1?action=append&position=0
```

Once you have received the 202 Accepted you can then call the `action=flush` and pass the position that you want the data to be flushed.

```
https://$STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME.dfs.core.windows.net/mydata/data/file1?action=flush&position=13
```

[image]

Comment: : Can we get latest modified file from a folder ??

Comment: @steve Yeah,use `MODIFIED` :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/functions/metadata/file/file-modified

Comment: 'can you please share me sample code .. I tried but its not working for me.

Comment: @steve You mean modified method?

Comment: i tried like this.. but not working  '@'data = 
    EXTRACT 
      ...,
     modified_date = FILE.MODIFIED(), 
     created_date = FILE.CREATED()
    FROM "/input/{*}.csv"
    USING Extractors.Csv();  '@'data =
SELECT *
FROM '@'data
WHERE created_date > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);